# How to filter json data with openjson in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this json:

```
{
   "personalLoans":{
      "loans":[]
   },
   "loanHistory":{
      "loans":[
         {
            "role":"Kredimarrës",
            "type":"1"
         },
         {
            "role":"Kredimarrës",
            "type":"2"
         },
         {
            "role":"Kredimarrës",
            "type":"3"
         },
         {
            "role":"Tjetër",
            "type":"4"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What I want to do is to filter only the loan history data that have role with value 'Kredimarrës', so as a result i will get 3 rows with data 1,2,3

So far, I have this script

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json1)
     WITH (personalLoans NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.personalLoans' AS JSON,
           loanHistory NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.loanHistory' AS JSON)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(loanHistory)
      WITH (hloans NVARCHAR(max) '$.loans' AS JSON)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(hloans)
      WITH (hrole NVARCHAR(max) '$.role')
WHERE hrole  = 'Kredimarrës'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating this. You can pass a JSON path to `OPENJSON` to jump directly to `$.loanHistory.loans`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json1, '$.loanHistory.loans')
  WITH (
    role nvarchar(100),
    type int
  ) h
WHERE h.role = N'Kredimarrës';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b193a1571075b0b66fd7889d2642e09)